# Inexplicably different results between using os/exec and executing at the command line

Tags: windows, go, command-line

I write a program which run a command use package `os/exec` in Golang.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("taskkill", "/f /im VInTGui.exe")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

When I run that program , it printed: `err: exit status 1`

But when I run command `taskkill /f /im VInTGui.exe` in Windows Command Line. It success.

Why run command by package `os/exec` and run command directly by `Windows Command Line` (using same user same permissions) has Different result? How can I fix my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the `Stderr` property of the `Command` object. This can be done like this:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("taskkill", "/f /im VInTGui.exe")
var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %s\n", err, stderr.String())
    return
}
fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())
```

In your case, just change

```golang
exec.Command("taskkill", "/f /im VInTGui.exe")
```

to

```golang
exec.Command("taskkill", "/f", "/im",  "VInTGui.exe")
```

Don't merge all arguments to one string.